# How flexible is the routes file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Please correct me if any of the assumptions I am making is wrong but here is what I think:

When we use a new "**resource**" in the routes file, to have a let's say new GET REST API, it is better to also use a new "**controller**" for that resource.

Now when we use **a new controller** we also get **a new default route** based on the name of that controller. *Here is where my question starts :)*

I already do have a controller and a GET REST so for example I have a `health_mamagment` controller and then a URL like `/health_managment/id.json`

So now while I am on that URL,  well it has a couple of more navigation links - like Tabs in Windows Apps- so the user could click on some other link and needs to see some new data. ( still it is the same WorkFlow, he just wants to see some new data).

So Here I am calling a new GET REST API to get the new data for a link for example called Payers

So does a URL like `/health_managment/id/payes`   make sense?

But if we go and create a new controller and resource for this new "payers" view, then in the routes file can I somehow with maybe use "as" keyword? and map the new route to be `/health_managment/id/payes`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest resources in your route file and specify the controller to use :

```
 # /config/routes.rb
 resources :health_managment do
   resources :payes, :controller => "Payer" do
     member do
       # Your custom routes
     end
   end
 end
```

This will lead to the fact that you can use the url 
/health_managment/id/payes

as an access to your "Payer" controller.

Using :as will not modify the URI endpoint but will modify the named helpers as stated here :
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html at section 4.

As requested in the comment, here is a more in depth look at the "member" part :

```
 # /config/routes.rb
 resources :posts do
   get 'recent'
   member do
       get 'abstract'
   end
 end
```

Will generate the custom urls :

- GET /posts/recent wich should display **a list of** posts. You are linking the url to the collection of posts
- GET /posts/:id/abstract wich should display **one post** (with the ID specified) in an alternative manner

Alternatively, you could have written this route like that :

```
 # /config/routes.rb
 resources :posts do
   get 'recent', :on => :collection
   get 'abstract', :on => :member
 end
```

When you declare sub resources, they are set at the "member level", thus :

```
 # /config/routes.rb
 resources :posts do
   get 'recent', :on => :collection
   get 'abstract', :on => :member
   resources :comments do
      # Routes again
   end
 end
```

Will let you access the URI /posts/:id/comments and define custom routes from there

Comment: I will research it myself too you but could you please explain a little bit what is the trick with the "member do end" section. I haven't used "member" before.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the URL you've proposed does make sense but how you map it in the routes file depends on the relationship between your health_management resource and payers resource.

I'd suggest you look at [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) if there is a has_many/belongs_to relationship between the two.  You can also do this manually using the following route:

```
get '/health_managment/:id/payers' => 'payers#index'
```

In your Payers controller file, you could then have the following index action:

```
def index
  @health_managment = HealthManagment.find(params[:id])
  @payers = @health_managment.payers
end
```

If you are working on an API though, it makes sense to constrain it to the usual REST structure and for this, nested resources works well.

Comment: Thanks. Between the two there is not a 1-many relationship. (So the nested resources goes away?)
 The second one is just another view, diagrams, json data for that link. But like I said it is not a whole new link, it is another link in the header of the same page, he clicks on it, wants to see some new data. And yes All these are just GET REST APIS that return JSON.

Comment: If I use the "get '/health_managment/:id/payers' => 'payers#index'"  then I won't need a new "resource" in the routes file? and I won't have a named route that I can use like *_path?

Comment: Exactly, you won't need a new resource. You can get a `_path` link by using `:as` e.g. `get '/health_managment/:id/payers' => 'payers#index', :as => 'payers'` would give you a `payers_path` named route.

Comment: Ok cool, so if I don't need a "new resource" for payers section, So I won't need a new controller either? So I can just add a new method like "showFoo" to the controller of the existing health_managment controller and map to that action method in the route?  Please Note that the way you have written your index isn't efficinet, at any point of time we are in one of the views, so we don't need to return JSON for both of them thus breaking it into two methods...for two views..one in payer..one in population_managment

Comment: You can add a method `showFoo` but best practice would be to have a specific controller for Payers.

Comment: great. Thanks.  Yes looking for "the best practice." . So to summarize: Use new controller...do Not use new Resource in routes file. Use that GET and AS syntax to map the new URL.

Comment: Robin what do you think about nested resources? is it overkill? As suggested by the other answer on this page.

Comment: No, not overkill. Both solutions are viable in my view.